# dynamically select Ienumerable property in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I am trying to do following assert

```
Assert.AreEqual<string>(A.Drivers[i].FirstName, Response);
```

Drivers is **IEnumerable** collection and it has other properties like last name , middle name etc. I'd like to dynamically select the properties of Drivers so it can be done in one method rather than writing different methods for each property

Comment: What is `i`?  Are you currently doing this in a loop?  Should the assertion fail if *any* item in `Drivers` fails, or only if *all* items in `Drivers` fails?

Comment: Hmm, you say "so it can be done in one method" but I only see one method there. Could you give an example of what it would look like if you were to have a method for each property? It's hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: You said that Drivers is an IEnumerable collection... Collection of what? Are all of the properties on said object of type string?

Comment: this question is actually (I think). "How can I read a runtime specified property of an object?" Javascript allows obj["propname"] c# has no simple equivalent You need to use reflection as per Dano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using reflexion:

get string properties of the Drivers class

```
var driverProperties = typeof(Drivers).GetProperties().Where(i => i.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)));
```

and then iterate through the properties

```
foreach (var property in driverProperties)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual<string>(property.GetValue(A.Drivers[i]), Response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

slight change to Dano suggestion. To get one specific property

```
var prop = typeof(Drivers).GetProperty("propName");
var val = (string)prop.GetValue(A.Drivers[i]);
```